# Get input of txt file from user in Console.net in CSharp

Tags: c#, .net, terminal, console

I'm using csharp in console.net
I want to get a txt file from the user as input
But I do not want the text inside the txt file to be displayed to the user
Instead, I want the text to be hidden and the number of lines to be displayed instead

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you fine, you want to count the number of lines in the txt file, right?
A basic approach could be:

```
string[] fileLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("<path to the file>");
if (fileLines != null)
Console.WriteLine($"The file has {fileLines.Length} lines.");
```

Comment: True, I want the number of lines, but I want to drag and drop the txt file to the terminal

Comment: Hi, I don´t think you can do it out of the box.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure I'm 100% clear on what you want , @XxMaHdIxX. But you can prompt the user to drag and drop the file: `Console.WriteLine("Please drag and drop a file to the console window.");` and then `string filePath = Console.ReadLine();`. Then replace `<path to the file>`  with `filePath`. When the user drags and drops the file, it will be as if the filename was typed in. Then hit enter, and you will get the number of lines.

Comment: Hi, I don´t think you can do it out of the box.
 Specially because Drag&Drop event are on Forms namespace, and a console application no.  Please, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.dodragdrop?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

Comment: You can put this code together and ready (the2step)